# PHP Variable with wordwrap

Tags: php, variables

I got an exercise from my University. We made a Website with PHP in Netbeans, with database and all that.

Now I got a problem. I have to type in a name let's say "Germany", that will save that name in a variable $seminarbezeichnung. Now I have to show that in the website and it should split in "Ger" and after that a wordwrap "many"(just a simple example, we have to do something like after 15 characters, so it wont be too long).

The thing now is, that I couldn't do it, because I am not that good in PHP :D

I did something like this:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $neuertext = wordwrap($seminarbezeichnung, 20, "<br />\n");


        echo $neuertext
```

Shouldn't that make a wordwrap after 20 characters?

I Hope you can help me :)
[image]
You see that at the left side it won't do a wordwrap after 20 characters

Thanks for helping and sorry for my english, not a native speaker

Comment: For a propper word wrap you need a dictionary, since you cannot simply split words in a human readable language wherever you like.

Comment: Check the 4th parameter of http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php . In short, `wordwrap` won't break a word unless the 4th parameter is true.

Comment: Thank you all! The Problem was with the 4th parameter

Comment: Alternatively you can use the CSS3 word-break attribute:  `word-break: break-all; width: 70em;`

Answer (score 2):

The [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function has a `$cut` parameter. It is `false` by default so it won't force cut long words.

> If the cut is set to TRUE, the string is always wrapped at or before the specified width. So if you have a word that is larger than the given width, it is broken apart. (See second example). When FALSE the function does not split the word even if the width is smaller than the word width.

Also note that the wordwrap function does not work properly with multibyte character encodings (like UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I changed it to:

Comment: $neuertext = wordwrap($seminarbezeichnung, 20, "<br />\n", true); 
            
            echo "<tr><td>" . $neuertext